# Given a string which is in svg i want to add id to the text element of the svg, and id will the content between the text enclosed

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

Given a string that is in SVG I want to add the id to the text element of the SVG, and id will the content between the text enclosed.

for example

`<svg><text>2</text> <text>3</text></svg>`

Output
`<svg><text id ="2">2</text><text id="3">3</text></svg>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var svgelement = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var childNodes = svgelement.childNodes;
[].forEach.call(childNodes, function (child) {
    if (child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName == "text") {
        child.setAttribute('id', child.innerHTML);
    }
});

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]);
```

```html
<svg>
    <text>2</text>
    <text>3</text>
</svg>
```

If SVG is given in string, you can do the following:

```js
var svg = '<svg><text>2</text><text>3</text></svg>';

svgContainer = document.getElementById("svgContainer");
svgContainer.innerHTML = svg;

var svgelement = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var childNodes = svgelement.childNodes;
[].forEach.call(childNodes, function (child) {
    if (child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName == "text") {
        child.setAttribute('id', child.innerHTML);
    }
});

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].outerHTML); // If you want the output as string
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]); // If you want the output as HTMLElement
```

```html
<div id="svgContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Svg is given in string

Comment: @MayankSharma, please have a look at my alternative solution I've updated to the answer.